# State of the art method for non-convex optimization of $\|x\|_p$

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus

The following mathematical optimization program is non convex for $0\leq p<1$, and some convex function $f$:

$$\text{minimize}_x \|x\|^p_p+f(x)$$

I'm wondering if any one knows the state of the art method for solving this problem?

1-It is clear that we can apply a sub-gradient minimization (and reach to a local minimum), but I'm wondering if there are better approaches out there or not?

2-if there exist such approaches what's the theoretical reason that makes them better.

Thanks for your help!

By the way $\|x\|_p^p$ is defined as the following: $$\|x\|_p^p=\sum_i |x_i|^p$$

Comment: heuristic/esoteric stuff like simulated annealing?

Comment: I personally prefer general purpose solutions that have theoretic proofs, but could you please explain your specific approach for solving this problem? how do you use simulated annealing to solve this problem?

Comment: i understand it in this way: you dont have any idea about how to proof [your system is lower semi continuous/your solution is unique/your system of first order makes sense]. then take this stuff to have at least an heuristic algorithm. In princilpe works like this: Try any point in an "environment" of your current "optimum". Take a certain exponentially distributed propability to accept a candidate as new optimum even thought it's more costly than the current optimum. Then iterate and iterate. Then decrease the propability of accepting a worse worse optimum. iterate. decrease. iterate. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this paper:

"IMPROVED ITERATIVELY REWEIGHTED LEAST SQUARES FOR
UNCONSTRAINED SMOOTHED $\ell_q$ MINIMIZATION", By MING-JUN LAI , YANGYANG XU, AND WOTAO YIN

http://www.caam.rice.edu/~wy1/paperfiles/Rice_CAAM_TR11-12_Mtx_Rcvry_ncvx_Lq.PDF

I think it exactly refers to the same problem.

Update: The original link above is broken, but I found it again here:

https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/papers/pdf/Rice_CAAM_TR11-12_Mtx_Rcvry_ncvx_Lq.pdf

Comment: Yes it does, Thanks!